# Error when creating template based trigger

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have a web check rule that does the following:-

1. Use a web scenario to test the website is up or down
2. Checks whetherthe domain is coming up to renewal
3. Checks the SSL expiry date

I am trying to configure a trigger that will get used in conjunction with the web scenario.

Here is what I have

```
{{HOST.NAME:web.test.fail[Check {HOST.NAME} is up].last()}}<>0
```

There is a valid website address that gets picked up correctly when I specify the host address, but when I use the macro I get the following error

Incorrect trigger expression. Check expression part starting from "{{HOST.NAME:web.test.fail[Check {HOST.NAME} is up].last()}}<>0".

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I needed this

```
{Template Website Availability Checks:web.test.fail[Check {HOST.NAME} is up].last()}<>0
```